Why does bounded curvature mean that ricci flow has solution?
Picture below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces. In this paper, the author consider the equation
$$
\partial_t g_{ij}=(r-R)g_{ij} \tag{1}
$$
where $r$ is the average of $R$. From the 4.7 Corollary, seemly, the author think that  when the curvature is bounded, the solution exist.  I've actually seen this expression in many places, but I've never really thought about it. The equation of curvature is
$$
\partial_t R=\Delta R +R^2 -rR  \tag{2}
$$
which is  get from (1).




This is proved in Hamilton’s first paper on the Ricci flow
